# Disable date actions in iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview, text-recognition, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a time slot picker web component on a page that is shown with WKWebView in an iOS app.

iOS recognises that the given text is a date an offers actions when you click on the date.

Is there any way to disable that? Either by changing the HTML code or configuring the iOS WKWebView instance?

[image: Actual image]

HTML code:

```
<header class="cSlot-dates-selector svelte-kvfxh4">
    <div class="cSlot-day svelte-10whff3 today">
        <span class="cSlot-date-name svelte-10whff3">Thu</span> 
        <span class="cSlot-date-nb svelte-10whff3">29 Jul</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cSlot-day svelte-10whff3">
        <span class="cSlot-date-name svelte-10whff3">Fri</span>
        <span class="cSlot-date-nb svelte-10whff3">30 Jul</span>
   </div>
   //...
</header>
```

If you press next, the HTML is updated and the action will not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JavaScript code to 'override' so to speak the HTML and disabling long presses and link touches:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { elems[i]['href'] = 'javascript:(void)'; }")
}
```